# Couldn't import Django

Tags: python, django

I am trying to run django from virtualenv but i am getting this error:

**Error**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 11, in main
    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django.core'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 17, in main
    ) from exc
ImportError: Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you forget to activate a virtu?
(
```

when i imported django from python shell,i got this:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django.core'
```

i checked if django is installed.

```
(welpieenv) root@li2180-35:~/welpie# source welpieenv/bin/activate
(welpieenv) root@li2180-35:~/welpie# pip install django
Requirement already satisfied: django in ./welpieenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages (3.1.6)
Requirement already satisfied: sqlparse>=0.2.2 in ./welpieenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from django) (0.4.1)
Requirement already satisfied: asgiref<4,>=3.2.10 in ./welpieenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from django) (3.3.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz in ./welpieenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from django) (2021.1)
(welpieenv) root@li2180-35:~/welpie# pip3 install django
Requirement already satisfied: django in ./welpieenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages (3.1.6)
Requirement already satisfied: sqlparse>=0.2.2 in ./welpieenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from django) (0.4.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz in ./welpieenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from django) (2021.1)
Requirement already satisfied: asgiref<4,>=3.2.10 in ./welpieenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from django) (3.3.1)
```

As you guys can see virtualenv is activated.Why am i getting this error?

Comment: You really, really, _really_ shouldn't be working as `root`.

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/16178/why-is-it-bad-to-log-in-as-root explains some reasons.

Comment: Show us this output from a python shell: `import django; print(django.__file__)`

Comment: You might have some file like `django.py` from where you are executing rename it to something else.

Comment: if you are are having multiple python versions installed, then you might face this issue. If you are using 'python manage.py' , try using 'python3 manage.py' instead. This worked for me.

Comment: that might be the problem @ShivendraPratapKushwaha i am working on it right now.

Comment: problem solved.I removed multiple pythons and it worked

Comment: Great. Please update the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had multiple versions of Phyton installed (Phyton2.7&Python3.7). Uninstalling Python 2.7 solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you are are having multiple python versions installed, then you might face this issue. If you are using `python manage.py` , try using `python3 manage.py` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall Python from your computer and install latest version and then activate virtual environment in your directory.And then try again.

You can use this link as well-
Click [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/windows/)!

Comment: It is already solved,you can check out the green ticked answer!

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30719590)